# CPU intensive? PHP byte read gzip file to browser

Tags: php, gzip, benchmarking

I want to use a PHP script as an intermediary to serve a .JS.GZ file with appropriate response headers and caching headers. How much more CPU intensive is this as compared to just serving the file directly? How could I benchmark the CPU usage?

```
$file = fopen('autocomplete.js.gz', 'rb');
echo fpassthru($file);
```

Comment: You can benchmark it with [XDebug](http://xdebug.org/). But I suspect the answer to this question is "The difference, if there even is one, is so minimal that you don't need to worry about it". Also, check out the [`readfile()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.readfile.php) function. Also, doing `echo fpassthru()` is pointless and will result in corrupted data, since `fpassthru()` outputs data directly, and the `echo` will output an integer on the end of it - you should remove the `echo`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`readgzfile()`](http://php.net/readgzfile) is the most efficient solution PHP itself has to offer. The [inflate](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DEFLATE) decompression algorithm itself doesn't consume much CPU power, and has only a small memory footprint as well (well normally). It's one of the most optimized zlib functions.

Answer (score 1):

- Use [`readfile('autocomplete.js.gz');`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.readfile.php)
- There is an [Apache](http://codeutopia.net/blog/2009/03/06/sending-files-better-apache-mod_xsendfile-and-php/) module called [mod_xsendfile](http://codeutopia.net/blog/2009/03/06/sending-files-better-apache-mod_xsendfile-and-php/).

[Usage](http://codeutopia.net/blog/2009/03/06/sending-files-better-apache-mod_xsendfile-and-php/) of xsendfile:

```
<?php 
header('X-Sendfile: autocomplete.js.gz'); // does not use any PHP memory!
```